# Who introduced the symbol $\sqrt {x}$?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, notation

The question is already in the title.
I am interested in who was the first to introduce the symbol $\sqrt {.}$
I was asked this question from one of my students -since as he said the symbol is bizarre-
If it is possible I would also like to see other notations that have been used for square roots through time. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is answered here http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2264/why-is-the-radical-symbol-sqrt-called-radical/2265#2265 The radix symbol, without the overbar, was first used by Rudolff in 1525, the overbar was added by Descartes in La Geometrie (1637).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to check on this [site](http://jeff560.tripod.com/operation.html) :

> **Square root**. The first use of a capital R with a diagonal line was by [Leonardo of Pisa (or Fibonacci)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci) :
>
> The first appearance of the abbreviation R or R(with line) for *radix* is in his *Pradica geometriae* (1220), where one finds the R meaning "square root" in an expression "et minus R. 78125 dragme, et diminuta radice 28125 dragme."([Cajori](https://books.google.it/books?id=7juWmvQSTvwC&pg=PA90) vol. 1, page 90).

The radical symbol first appeared in 1525 in *Die Coss* by [Christoff Rudolff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoph_Rudolff) (1499-1545). He used the
symbol (without the vinculum) for square roots. He did not use indices to indicate higher roots, but instead modified the appearance of the radical symbol for higher roots.

---

The fundamental work on these topics is still :

- Florian Cajori, [A history of mathematical notations](https://books.google.it/books?id=7juWmvQSTvwC&pg=PA369), Volumes 1-2 (1919 - Dover reprint).